# Output Buffering with PHP Headers

Tags: php, http-headers, output-buffering

I am attempting to create a vcard from data within a WordPress install (WP part I'm assuming is inconsequential). I am calling the file with a URL param like `/inc/vcard.php?vcard=664` and have the following code so far:

```
<?php ob_start();

define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-blog-header.php' );

/**
 * Loads the WordPress environment and template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */
if ( !isset($wp_did_header) ) {
    $wp_did_header = true;
    require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );
    wp();
    require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );
}

if (isset($_GET['vcard'])) {
    $attorney_id = $_GET['vcard'];

    $post = get_post($attorney_id);
    $slug = $post->post_name;

    if (!$post || get_post_type() !== 'attorneys') {
        echo 'Invalid attorney';
        return;
    }

    function field_check($field) {
        echo get_field($field) ? get_field($field) : '';
    }

    ?>

    BEGIN:VCARD
    VERSION:3.0
    REV:<?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
    FN:<?php field_check('first_name'); ?> <?php field_check('middle_initial'); ?> <?php field_check('last_name'); ?>
    N:<?php field_check('last_name'); ?>;<?php field_check('first_name'); ?> <?php field_check('middle_initial'); ?>

    TITLE:<?php field_check('position'); ?>

    ORG: Odin, Feldman &amp; Pittleman P.C.

    ADR;WORK:;;1775 Wiehle Avenue, Suite 400;Reston;Virginia;20190;United States of America

    URL:<?php field_check('blog_url'); ?>

    TEL;TYPE=WORK;VOICE:<?php field_check('phone_number'); ?>

    TEL;TYPE=WORK;Fax:<?php field_check('fax_number'); ?>

    EMAIL;TYPE=internet,pref:<?php field_check('email'); ?>

    URL;TYPE=WORK:<?php the_permalink(); ?>

    TZ:-0400
    END:VCARD

    <?php header('Content-Type: text/x-vcard; charset=utf-8');header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $slug . '.vcf"'); exit();
}
else {
    echo 'Invalid input.';
}
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $output;
```

But it seems like the output buffering either isn't working correctly or I'm still not connecting how to use the two (headers and output buffering) together. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

As a quick note, I am calling this function outside of WordPress, so that is why I am "including" WordPress after the start of the output buffer.

### Update

After both suggestions (setting the headers outside of the buffer and moving the `exit();` to the bottom, there hasn't been any difference:

```
<?php ob_start();

define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-blog-header.php' );

/**
 * Loads the WordPress environment and template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */
if ( !isset($wp_did_header) ) {
    $wp_did_header = true;
    require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );
    wp();
    require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );
}

if (isset($_GET['vcard'])) {
    $attorney_id = $_GET['vcard'];

    $post = get_post($attorney_id);
    $slug = $post->post_name;

    if (!$post || get_post_type() !== 'attorneys') {
        echo 'Invalid attorney';
        return;
    }

    function field_check($field) {
        echo get_field($field) ? get_field($field) : '';
    }

    ?>

    BEGIN:VCARD
    VERSION:3.0
    REV:<?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
    FN:<?php field_check('first_name'); ?> <?php field_check('middle_initial'); ?> <?php field_check('last_name'); ?>
    N:<?php field_check('last_name'); ?>;<?php field_check('first_name'); ?> <?php field_check('middle_initial'); ?>

    TITLE:<?php field_check('position'); ?>

    ORG: Odin, Feldman &amp; Pittleman P.C.

    ADR;WORK:;;1775 Wiehle Avenue, Suite 400;Reston;Virginia;20190;United States of America

    URL:<?php field_check('blog_url'); ?>

    TEL;TYPE=WORK;VOICE:<?php field_check('phone_number'); ?>

    TEL;TYPE=WORK;Fax:<?php field_check('fax_number'); ?>

    EMAIL;TYPE=internet,pref:<?php field_check('email'); ?>

    URL;TYPE=WORK:<?php the_permalink(); ?>

    TZ:-0400
    END:VCARD

    <?php
}
else {
    echo 'Invalid input.';
}
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
header('Content-Type: text/x-vcard; charset=utf-8');header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $slug . '.vcf"');
echo $output;
exit();
```

### Update #2

I've revised the code more to make sure there's no stray lines anywhere:

```
<?php ob_start();

$slug = 'vcard';

define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-blog-header.php' );

/**
 * Loads the WordPress environment and template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */
if ( !isset($wp_did_header) ) {
    $wp_did_header = true;
    require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );
    wp();
    require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );
}

if (isset($_GET['vcard'])) {
    $attorney_id = $_GET['vcard'];

    $post = get_post($attorney_id);
    $slug = $post->post_name;

    if (!$post || get_post_type() !== 'attorneys') {
        return 'Invalid attorney';
    }

    function field_check($field) {
        echo get_field($field) ? get_field($field) : '';
    }

?>
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
REV:<?php echo get_the_date(); ?>

FN:<?php field_check('first_name'); ?> <?php field_check('middle_initial'); ?> <?php field_check('last_name'); ?>

N:<?php field_check('last_name'); ?>;<?php field_check('first_name'); ?> <?php field_check('middle_initial'); ?>

TITLE:<?php field_check('position'); ?>

ORG: Odin, Feldman &amp; Pittleman P.C.
ADR;WORK:;;1775 Wiehle Avenue, Suite 400;Reston;Virginia;20190;United States of America
URL:<?php field_check('blog_url'); ?>

TEL;TYPE=WORK;VOICE:<?php field_check('phone_number'); ?>

TEL;TYPE=WORK;Fax:<?php field_check('fax_number'); ?>

EMAIL;TYPE=internet,pref:<?php field_check('email'); ?>

URL;TYPE=WORK:<?php the_permalink(); ?>

TZ:-0400
END:VCARD<?php
}
else {
    return 'Invalid input.';
}
$output = ob_get_contents();
header('Content-Type: text/x-vcard');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$slug.'.vcf');
return $output;
exit();
```

But still haven't gotten anywhere. I did notice there's no "headers already sent" message, but a "webpage not found" when trying to load this. If I take out the headers call, this is some sample input I get:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
REV:November 4, 2013
FN:Sample Name
N:Adams;Robert C.
TITLE:Shareholder
ORG: Sample Company
ADR;WORK:;;Street;City;State;12345;United States of America
URL:
TEL;TYPE=WORK;VOICE:(555) 123-4567
TEL;TYPE=WORK;Fax:(555) 123-4567
EMAIL;TYPE=internet,pref:sample@test.com
URL;TYPE=WORK:http://www.google.com
TZ:-0400
END:VCARD
```

Now that's in the source-view, but in the browser it's all on one line -- does that matter when rendering the header as a vcard? Thanks!

Comment: You have to send the header after getting the contents and cleaning of the output buffer.

Comment: Thanks for this - please seem my updated question for progress; or lack thereof I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the exit()  so your code does not stop before you send the output.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help - I've edited my original question with my progress. Thanks.